# Java Integration Testing. When to use Embedded Server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, continuous-integration, integration-testing

We're in the process of writing Integration Tests for `Java EE` application and can't agree on one thing.

Should the integration tests run on an embedded server vs. the real one?

Are there really any benefits in running tests on a full-fledged Java EE server?

I actually see a lot of problems in this approach, the biggest one being is that we should somehow expose `EJB` business methods either through `@Remote` interface or through some `Web Service`.

Also, we're planning to run these integration tests on `Jenkins` server. We're already have one build configuration that packages our app and deploys it onto a `Glassfish` server. So, maybe having this in mind, should affect our decision, whether to use embedded or real server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute tests against `@Local` views of EJBs you either embedded the container in the test vm or embedding the test in the container.

You can have your cake and eat it too ... do both :) The Arquillian API is nice enough that you can have one test that can be configured to do both.

Run tests quickly as you develop with an embedded container like [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org), then in Jenkins run them again against something that looks like the production server (this will be slower).

Don't limit yourself into thinking you need to choose just one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

It's not important if a server is embedded or not. But it needs to have very fast startup and low memory consumption. This way you ca run them locally on the developer machines. Advantages:

- the tests will be run more often and bugs will be caught more rapidly
- is easier to write and debug tests when you can run them fast locally
- it allows for (easier) TDD
- certain features cannot be built at all without integration tests running on developer machines, for example a REST API.

And you don't need to expose the EJB with `@Remote` or as a web service to be run in an embedded server. In fact you don't need to modify them at all. I don't if you decided upon an Java EE integration framework or not, but you can take a look at [Arquilian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) for this.

I can also suggest [OpenEJB](http://openejb.codehaus.org/) as a fast EJB container for local integration testing.

Running the integration tests on Jenkins on real a (production) server tests for **commited** code. Is very useful as a one more safety net. But the developers should have themselves a way to test their code while developing and before committing.

Comment: Thank you. You have some valid points. But, like I said, the integration tests will be primarily run as a part of a Jenkins build, and the application will be deployed on a remote server anyway. That's why I doubt, whether it's worth starting an embedded server if the full-fledged one is already running. And yes, I'm already trying out Arquillian. Also, some of our colleagues claim that integration tests should run on a real environment. I'm confused :)

Comment: So, considering your edit, you think that as a part of `CI` it's better to run `IT` on a *real* environment?

Comment: yes, it's better. Jenkins runs on background and there speed is not that important.

Comment: Another problem is that I don't want to introduce @Remote interfaces just for testing. What do you think about that?

Comment: You wrote that @Remote interfaces aren't needed when testing on the **embedded** server, but what about testing on a *real* environment as a part of Jenkins build? Maybe there is a better alternative, without changing the API?

Comment: You should't need to modify your EJB API regrading of the type of server used embedded or standalone at least with Arquilian.

Comment: But then I won't be able to look them up on a remote server :( Except if their logic was exposed through a web service. So far, this is the only way to avoid API changes that I see.

Comment: Or, do you mean, that Arquillian is able to somehow look up EJB that doesn't have a @Remote interface? Well, if it does, then this is some sort of voodoo magic :)

Comment: You call the EJBs in your tests via their normal clients. If they are called from a JSF bean method you'll call this, if they are called from a web service you call the webservice, etc.

Comment: @jFrenetic not voodoo magic if you "embed" the test in the application being tested.  So you're either embedded the container in the test vm or embedding the test in the container if you want to test (at)Local.  Have your cake and eat it too and do both :)  The Arquillian API is nice enough that you can have one test that can be configured to do both.  Run tests quickly as you develop with an embedded container, then in Jenkins run it against something that looks like the production server (this will be slower).  Don't limit yourself into thinking you need to choose just one or the other.

Comment: @DavidBlevins Thanks! That's actually looks more like the answer to my question. If you write one, I would gladly accept it :) Yes, I've already noticed that Aruillian tests are packaged in the same EAR as application. At first I thought that the tests are executed in the local JVM.